# Optimizing MySQL FULLTEXT and proximity search query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relational-database

Consider the following table of `adverts` (creation using Laravel, but the code is pretty self explanatory):

```
Schema::create('adverts', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('id');      //PRIMARY KEY
   $table->string('name', 150);   //VARCHAR
   $table->text('description');   //TEXT

   $table->integer('city_id')->nullable();
   $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');

   $table->timestamps();
});
```

The `adverts` table has more columns, but these are the ones necessary right now imo. I want users to be able to find adverts with a text-search function so I added the following `FULLTEXT` index:

```
ALTER TABLE posts ADD FULLTEXT search(name, description)
```

As you can see each advert also has a `city_id` foreign key, that allows the user to search for `adverts` in a `city`, as well as in cities within a given radius. For this purpose I have a `radius` table, which contains records of pairs of cities and their distance from one another:

```
|  city_A  |   city_B   |distance|
----------------------------------
|    1     |     2      |  30    |
|    2     |     1      |  30    |
```

The `radius` table holds around 7 000 000 records and all of its columns are indexed. I have seeded the `adverts` table with around 100 000 fake records (descriptions are around 700 chars). When searching for adverts I execute the following Laravel query:

```
Advert::whereRaw('MATCH(name, description) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)', [$term])
       ->join('radius', function ($join) use ($radius, $id){
             $join->on('radius.secondary_id','=', 'posts.city_id');
        })->where('radius.primary_id', $id)
        ->whereBetween('radius.radius', [0,$radius]);
```

In SQL this translates to:

```
SLECT * FROM `adverts` 
INNER JOIN `radius` on `radius`.`city_B` = `posts`.`city_id` 
WHERE MATCH(name, description) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AND `radius`.`city_A` = ? 
AND `radius`.`radius` between ? and ?
ORDER BY `created_at` desc 
LIMIT 20
```

Ok so as I said the `adverts` table has a few more columns, but those don't seem to be causing major problems when performing a search query. However once I combine the `FULLTEXT` term search with the city proximity search the query takes a fairly long time to execute on my localhost - somewhere around 10-15 seconds. It seems like doing a `MATCH` on the entire `adverts` table works fine, `radius` search works fine but combined like this they result in a rather slow response.

**Is there something I can do to improve the tables or the query statements or is this a case where MySQL just wouldn't keep up?**

*My specs for the record:*

```
CPU: Intel Core i5 3450 @ 3.10GHz Quad
RAM: 8,00GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 665MHz
HDD: Seagate ST3320613AS ATA Device (SATA) 7200RPM 16MB Cache
```

---

EDIT: MySQL Explain of the inner join query:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+-----+---------+-----+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+-----+---------+--------+---+--+
| 1  |    SIMPLE   |adverts|fulltxt|adverts_city_id_foreign,| search | 0 |  | 1 | Using where; Using filesort |
|    |             |       |       | search                 |        |   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |   SIMPLE   | radius | ref  | city_A_index,| city_A_index| 5 | test_db.adverts.city_id | 1417 | Using where |
|    |            |        |      | city_B_index,|             |   |
|    |            |        |      | distances_ind|             |   |
+----+------------+--------+------+--------------+-------------+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Use `explain SELECT * FROM adverts ...` and post the result. You might need to tweak a few indexes, but you need to verify how is MySQL performing the join. Another good thing is to post the MySQL version and make sure you use the most up-to-date version (I've added issues with using older versions).

Comment: For your tests, did you remove the `order by`? Removing it will give a completely different result. I would try the indexes indexes `created_at, city_id` and `city_A, radius`.

Comment: I will do more testig tomorrow, but do you think it could help doing a `where city_id in(...)` and just doing a subselect on the radius table rather than a join?

Comment: @milz I have updated the question with the result of `EXPLAIN` used on an inner join query. I am quite clueless as to what most of it means. The search index on the adverts table is a `FULLTEXT search(name,description)` index. I was thinking - could creating an index on the radius table like this: `radius(city_B, distance)` help? My assumption is that that would be a decent one considering, that the users will always search for `adverts` in the form of `WHERE radius.city_B = ? AND radius.distance between 0 AND ?`

Comment: It might help, but I don't think that's the issue. Have you tried executing the query without the `ORDER BY `created_at` desc `? If you check the column `Extra` on the explain, you'll see that for the adverts table, MySQL is using a where and a filesort. This is what I think the issue is. I would go with a new index on the `adverts.created_at` table. Let me know how that goes. Thanks!

Comment: @milz Removing the `order by created_at` from the query removes `Using filesort` from the Extra column of mysql explain. But simply having an index for it does not seem like it even considers to use it. Because of the way the DB was seeded - a lot of records have the same timestamps. In the query above the only two indexes considered for the adverts table are the `city_id` index and the `search(name,description)` index. Will the query always choose the fulltext index if it needs to perform a `MATCH`? I have also added the `radius(city_B, distance)` index to the joined table and its picked.